# Different inputs for foreach in Powershell

Tags: powershell, types, foreach

I've got two beginner's questions regarding data types in Powershell.

1. why does these two commands differ in results?

   ```
   PS > $test = {"a", "b", "c"}
   PS > foreach ($item in $test) { $item | Out-Host }
   "a", "b", "c"
   PS > $test = "a", "b", "c"
   PS > foreach ($item in $test) { $item | Out-Host }
   a
   b
   c
   ```
2. One command returns data, which - when formatted as list - looks like the following:

   ```
   Changes              : {Change instance 10406282
                           ChangeType: Edit
                           (...)

                         , Change instance 25906333
                           ChangeType: Edit
                           (...)
                          }
   ```

   It looks like this is some kind of a list of items. How can I `foreach` through them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First question**
If you do following:
    $test = {"a", "b", "c"}
    $test.GetType()

```
$test = "a", "b", "c"
$test.GetType()
```

You will notice that the first object is `ScriptBlock` the second one is an array

**Second question**

Assign result to an object and simple iterate as you do above.

Simple example:

```
$result = (Get-TfsItemHistory $/<projectName> -all -user $name -Recurse -server $tfs)
$result | foreach {$item = $_; Write-Host $item; Write-Host $item.ChangeType;}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a simple example to your second answer? The first answer is clear.

Comment: I may, but that command comes from the tfs utils and you may not easily reproduce its results. That's `Get-TfsItemHistory $/<projectName> -all -user $name -Recurse -server $tfs` You may provide just a similar case, that will be absolutely enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

{...} creates a scriptblock, you might think that the loop runs 3 times but it's not (one iteration only), it just returns the content of the script block.

Items seperated by a comma creates a collection of items (array). When you loop over a collection you iterate over each item int he collection